# DIV with IE filter background allows mouse events to propagate below

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am showing a modal dialog in front of content of the screen.  Behind the dialog is the standard greyed out full screen DIV that is semi opaque.  To achieve the same effect in IE8 I use a filter as below:

```
#unlicensedOverlay {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#200000000', endColorstr='#20000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
```

This looks fine, but when you hover over buttons and links that the modal is over you can still click them and mouse events seem to fire, you can even select text. Note that this behaves perfectly when not in IE (if it was in any doubt)

How do I prevent this? I did try jQuery but this didnt work

```
$("#unlicensedOverlay").bind("click mousemove mouseover",function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: When you use filter in css for IE, strange things will always happen. I've created a lot of these overlays, and I always use an semi transparent image for IE. But try to use **pointer-events: none;** in #unlicensedOverlay

Comment: @MortenOC Thanks for this, unfortunately it doesnt work.. `pointer events: none` has the complete opposite effect ^_^